# Ubuntu 14.04 install png++

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to install png++ following the steps here http://www.nongnu.org/pngpp/doc/0.2.1/

But when i type make I get error

```
make -C example 
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/usr/Downloads/png++-0.2.9/example'
g++     pixel_generator.cpp   -o pixel_generator
pixel_generator.cpp:35:19: fatal error: png.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <png.hpp>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [pixel_generator] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/usr/Downloads/png++-0.2.9/example'
make: *** [examples] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to add the **-C example** on your make command. That changes to the wrong directory for make.

cd to /home/usr/Downloads/png++-0.2.9 (or wherever you have your source code), and issue a **make** (by itself) there, and a **make test** if you want the examples. **sudo make install** to install the final program.

Review the instructions at http://www.nongnu.org/pngpp/doc/0.2.1/